# Boost C++ UDP Socket stops receive after N packages

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I am sending udp packages from server to client. At the server side I split data into packages by 500 bytes, and sent to client. The client receives the packages and accumulate received data and deserializes an object.

The problem is that client receive 133 packages maximum and stops like nothing else was sent to socket, but server send whole object (1238 packages). And this problem exists in Windows only, but works perfectly under OSX.

Here is a server code sending packages:

```
// sends @buffer of size @length to @endpoint
// @buffer already contains a header, and the method splits @buffer into chunks and send it one by one
void server::send_package(char* buffer, int length, udp::endpoint endpoint){
    if (length > BUFFER){
        protocol::header header;
        int dataLength = length - sizeof (header);

        // copy header from buffer
        memcpy(&header, buffer, sizeof(header));
        header.isEnd = false;

        int position = 0;

        // allocate memory to collect data to send
        char* data_to_send = new char[dataLength];

        // copy data
        memcpy(data_to_send, &buffer[sizeof(header)], dataLength);
        header.totalPackages = dataLength/(BUFFER-sizeof (header));

        // create chucks of data and send
        while (position < dataLength){
            int frame_size = BUFFER;
            header.currentPackage++;
            if (dataLength-position+sizeof (header) <= BUFFER) {
                header.isEnd = true;
                frame_size = dataLength-position+sizeof (header);
            }
            char* temp_buffer = new char[frame_size];
            header.length = frame_size-sizeof(header);

            // set the header of a chunk
            memcpy(temp_buffer, &header, sizeof(header));

            // set data to chunk
            memcpy(&temp_buffer[sizeof (header)], &data_to_send[position], frame_size-sizeof(header));

            // send chunk
            socket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer(temp_buffer, frame_size), endpoint);
            socket->wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_write);

            position += frame_size-sizeof(header);
        }
    } else {
        socket->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, length), endpoint,
                              boost::bind(&server::release_sent_buffer,
                                          this,
                                          buffer, length)
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the client receives packages:

```
void connectionManager::handle_receive( const boost::system::error_code &error,
                                        std::size_t size,
                                        udp::endpoint* ep) {

    if (size > 0) {
       // _lock.try_lock();
        protocol::header header;
        memcpy(&header, &recv_buffer, sizeof(header));
        logg("response from server received " + boost::asio::ip::address_v4(header.ip).to_string());
        logg("received header:");
        logg(protocol::getHeaderInfo(header));
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "header.length = " << header.length;
        logg(ss.str().c_str());
        udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4(header.ip), _server_port);
        switch (header.command) {

             case protocol::commands::server_instance_instruments_state_response: {

                 package_chain chain(size-sizeof(header));
                 memcpy(chain.data, &recv_buffer[sizeof(header)], size-sizeof(header));
                 packages[header.id].push_back(chain);

                 // at Windows machine the last package is #133. But 1248 packages expected.
                 // WHY????...
                 int packs = (packages[header.id].size());

                 if (header.isEnd) {
                     char* buf = getDataFromPackages(header.id, header.length);
                     std::stringstream str;
                     str << buf;

                     boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(str);
                     instance_plugin_information* inst_inf;
                     inst_inf = new instance_plugin_information();
                     try {
                         ar & inst_inf;
                         if (onPluginStateResponse != nullptr) {
                             onPluginStateResponse(*inst_inf);
                         }
                     } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                         
                     }
                 }
                 break;
             }
  }
        // We will hang on this line when package #133 received.
        socket->wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read);
        connectionManager::start_receive();
}
```

I just don't understand what I am missing? Why client receives exactly 133 packages (133 x 500 bytes) and then drops?

I have changed the code in many ways, but with no luck. The last thing I added is

```
socket->wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read);
```

before I call `start_receive()` again, and the program hands on this line exactly when package #133 is received.

Please help. I am close to give up and become a pizza delivery guy.

Comment: UDP does not have guaranteed delivery at all

Comment: (Please don't deliver pizza over UDP, because delivery wouldn't be guaranteed either)

Comment: @sehe I know. But why client hangs on socket->wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read); ? There is no guaranty a package will be delivered, yes. But why after 500x133 bytes a client socket is not ready to read anymore? And it reproduced all the time: just 133 packets, then dead.

Comment: I suppose there can be explanations, but it's hard without an actual reproducer (and no access to a windows machine). It's not strange that `wait_read` doesn't complete when nothing arrives - there won't be anything to read if it doesn't get delivered.

Comment: One theory might be that the server burst the max. UDP buffer capacity (e.g 500x133 or maybe 500xmax UDP packet) and it sends so much faster than they're being received that the rest are just getting dropped by the OS IP stack

Comment: You could easily check by adding, say 5ms delays between packets, or changing the size per packet etc.

Comment: @sehe Playing with the buffer size sent via UDP shows that this is data limitation. You are right. 500x133 ~ 1024x65 ~ 66500.  Changing a delay between packets did not help. But I found a light: the client socket is constantly sending a ping signal every 50 ms. If I turn it off, then all packets are received. Async sending blocks async receiving somehow?